# SQL Session State & Javascript Error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, session-state

I've switch session storage to SQL server via:

```
    <sessionState mode="SQLServer"
           sqlConnectionString="data source= jim; user id=jim;password=jim;"
           cookieless="false"
           timeout="20" />

  </system.web>
```

and now I'm getting the following error in this code

```
var eventArgs = new Sys.WebForms.EndRequestEventArgs(error, data ? data.dataItems : {}, executor);
Sys.Observer.raiseEvent(this, "endRequest", eventArgs);
if (error && !eventArgs.get_errorHandled()) {
    throw error;
}
```

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
>   An unknown error occurred while
>   processing the request on the server.
>   The status code returned from the
>   server was: 500

If I leave session as the default rather than SQL Server it works fine.
One further point, I can add items to the session OK - this seems to be occurring when the page is reloaded - maybe some kind of AJAX issue?

In terms of setting up SQL Session storage I did this:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604

The app works fine when I run it.

Thanks in advance.

Jim

EDIT - In the application log I can now see:
'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' in Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not marked as serializable.

... and true enough, I am adding a list item to the view state.
But why does this work OK - except when storing session in SQL?]

Thanks again!

Jim

Comment: Can you add/retrieve items from the session and display on screen?

Comment: Also, check if there are any entries in Event Viewer of the server form ASP.NET. It might have written out a stack trace.

Comment: Hi - yes... adding and retrieving from session is OK

Comment: @gbvb - good call - I've updated my original question to reflect what was in the log. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to fire EndRequest manually? Your session works all right, maybe it has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: It must be that you used InProcess session storage earlier, which does no serialization. The error log states what the problem is.

Comment: I don't call EndRequest... thats generated code from, I guess, AJAX...

Comment: Let us know what you ended up doing, if possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you need to externalize/serialize content, it needs to call serialize to get a stream. ListItem is a UI control that you should not have to serialize.. :) http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/322990-serializing-drop-down-list-data-sources-session-state